# error assigning value to variable in snackbar

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, android-snackbar

try to change the value of **Variables.deleted** to be **false**, but when I checked it in the if statement it still **true**
what is the right way to do this function

```
 @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                final int pos = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                String noteID = allNotes.get(pos).getNoteID();
                final UserNote userNote =
                        new UserNote(allNotes.get(pos).getNoteTitle(),allNotes.get(pos).getNoteDesc(),allNotes.get(pos).getNoteDate(),allNotes.get(pos).getNoteID());
                allNotes.remove(pos);
                notesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Snackbar.make(recyclerView,"note deleted", BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Undo", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                Variables.deleted = false;
                                allNotes.add(pos,userNote);
                                notesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }).show();
                if (Variables.deleted){
                    databaseNotesReference.child(noteID).removeValue();
                }
            }
```

Comment: How is this question related to database?

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it

```
if (!Variables.deleted){
                    databaseNotesReference.child(noteID).removeValue();
                }
            }
```